# Don't cache current (index) page with cache manifest

Tags: html, caching, manifest

By default, when a cache manifest is used the browser will also cache the current (HTML) page. How do I ***not*** do that?

My site looks like `domain.com/` in the address bar but it is actually serving `domain.com/index.php`. I have tried:

```
NETWORK
/
*
```

and

```
NETWORK
/index.php
*
```

...and variants like index.html, index.php without the leading slash, etc. (The manifest is working fine otherwise -- it's properly caching some files listed under the `CACHE:` heading, it's being served with the correct MIME type, etc.)

Comment: Do you have something like <html manifest="application.appcache"> in your index.php ? If so, this is the normal behaviour. Why don't you want the main entry point of your application to be cached ?

Comment: Yes, that's in my main index.php. I don't want it to be cached because that page loads different content each time.

How else can I tell browsers to store my JS/CSS files offline? Maybe that's not what the manifest is for and I need to open a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put the manifest reference in your index.php.  Put it in a page you do want cached, or that you don't mind having cached, and load that page in an `iframe` on your index.php page.

Comment: Good idea. Of course there are drawbacks to both suggestions, but it does work. I am inserting the `iframe` with JS so it only loads the dummy page once. I'm using a cookie to track whether the `iframe` has been loaded.